# The DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported by IIS integrated pipeline mode

Tags: iis, iis-8

We are having issues in hosting Webforms apps in one of the windows 2012 servers and IIS8.5. The server causes "DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest method is not supported by IIS integrated pipeline mode" exception.

Attaching a screen shot for your reference[image]

However when I tested in another server it works all fine. To isolate issues I have even tried to deploy a sample webforms app and try out.

I need integrated mode pipe line as I have a requirement around it. 
I have verified the servers and there is no difference in iis configurations. What could be the possible reasons for this? Any guidance to narrow down the issue will really help.

Attaching the server comparison report.[image] The image shows the differences in two servers. in the right side server the application does not work and in the left side server it works. If you see the diff there is not a lot of changes and btw the changes are because I added them as part of trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We compared every possible stuff on the servers and finally decided to take up the server in which it is working. The server in which it didnot work might have some issues with they way IIS was deployed.

So in a way there was no way out for this problem for me.